# Dynamic SQL With Double Quoting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am attempting to run a dynamic SQL statement and it works for any `storename` that does not have an apostrophe in it.  However, when the `storename` has an apostrophe in it the syntax does not properly, however I am stuck using dynamic SQL in this instance.

How should I ammend this syntax in order for `storename` to include an apastrophe?

Here is DDL

```
Declare @TestHyphens Table(StoreName varchar(500),topItemSale varchar(500))

Insert Into @TestHyphens (StoreName, topItemSale) Values
('Bob''s Burger''s','Pen'), ('Jacks Coffee Shop','Pencil')
,('Larry''s Hair Shack','Rainbow'), ('Manny''s Sandwich Shop','Sunglasses')

Declare @sql nvarchar(4000), @storename varchar(500)

Declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR
Select StoreName
FROM @TestHyphens

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        Set @storename = REPLACE(@storename, '''', '''''''''');

        SET @storename = CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+@storename+CHAR(39)+CHAR(39);

        SET @SQL = N'Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN ('+@storename+ N')'

        Print @storename
        Print @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename

END

Close db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And print statements produce:

```
''Bob''''s Burger''''s''
Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN (''Bob''''s Burger''''s'')
''Jacks Coffee Shop''
Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN (''Jacks Coffee Shop'')
''Larry''''s Hair Shack''
Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN (''Larry''''s Hair Shack'')
''Manny''''s Sandwich Shop''
Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN (''Manny''''s Sandwich Shop'')
```

And as you can see these are incorrectly hyphenated -

```
''Manny''''s Sandwich Shop''
''Larry''''s Hair Shack''
''Bob''''s Burger''''s''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can temporarily change QUOTED_IDENTIFIER.

```
DECLARE @TestHyphens TABLE(StoreName varchar(500),topItemSale varchar(500))

INSERT INTO @TestHyphens (StoreName, topItemSale) VALUES
('Bob''s Burger''s','Pen'),
('Jacks Coffee Shop','Pencil'),
('Larry''s Hair Shack','Rainbow'), 
('Manny''s Sandwich Shop','Sunglasses');

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SELECT StoreName, TopItemSale 
FROM   @TestHyphens 
WHERE  StoreName = "Bob's Burger's"

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

| StoreName      | topItemSale |
|----------------|-------------|
| Bob's Burger's | Pen         |
```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/SDH36970)*

**Using within the cursor**

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX), @storename varchar(500)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT StoreName
FROM #TestHyphens

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = N'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF '
               + N'Select * from #TestHyphens where StoreName = "' + @storename + N'"'
               + N'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON';

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;    

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This is the result:

```
| StoreName             | topItemSale |
|-----------------------|-------------|
| Bob's Burger's        | Pen         |
| Jacks Coffee Shop     | Pencil      |
| Larry's Hair Shack    | Rainbow     |
| Manny's Sandwich Shop | Sunglasses  |
```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/LMEU45616)*

Comment: How would I implement this in my dynamic SQL case?

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: I get an error of 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. - is this SQL Server 2008 R2 friendly?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'll change it by +

Comment: This works!  SET @SQL = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF Select * from TestHyphens where storename = "' + storename + '" SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON'; Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help-.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many hyphens going on. I was able to successfully test it using this for the cursor:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        SET @storename = REPLACE(@storename, '''', '''''');

        SET @storename = CHAR(39)+@storename+CHAR(39);

        SET @sql = N'Select * from @TestHyphens where StoreName IN ('+@storename+ N')'

        PRINT @storename
        PRINT @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename

END
```

Comment: Removing one CHAR(39) and a set of the single quotes in my replace statement, changes the output from ''Bob''''s Burger''''s'' TO 'Bob''s Burger''s' - so instead of having triple quotes before the s I only have double now.  Still syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but this:

```
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   Print @storename
        Set @storename = REPLACE(@storename, '''', '''''''''');
   Print @storename
        SET @storename = CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+@storename+CHAR(39)+CHAR(39);

        SET @SQL = N'Select * from @TestHyphens where storename IN ('+@storename+ N')'

        Print @storename
        Print @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @storename

END
```

outputs the following, is not the first one what you are after?

```
Manny's Sandwich Shop
Manny''''s Sandwich Shop
''Manny''''s Sandwich Shop''
```

Comment: Yes the 1st one is my desired output.  I added in the replace statement as the single quote needs to be double quoted in the Where clause or an error of Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Bob'. is presented.